# How can I call a function from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In JavaScript how to call a function from another function. My function  is called Cheese and it alerts a hello cheese by passing it to another variable called X. I am practicing javascript functions.

```
 function cheese() {
     return function() {
         alert('hello cheese');
     };
 }
 var x = cheese();
 alert(x);
```

Comment: First off, welcome to StackOverflow - it appears you are new here.  Second off, you really should format your code correctly with proper indentation when posting (I fixed it for you).  Third off, you should describe what result you're trying to achieve.  So far, you just show some code that doesn't do anything useful which will just invite answers about why it doesn't do anything useful.  If you explain what you were trying to accomplish, then you would get answers that illustrate how to do that.

Comment: Thank-you for your feedback and correcting the formatting of my code.  I am  learning javascript. The hardest part was how to format my questions. It just said to  indent 4 spaces so I indented and also I couldn't figure out how to put the context in terms of StackOverflow standards.   But anyways,I  was reading the book Javascript 24hour trainer and on page 31 I couldn't understand their code and I was just simulating it.

Comment: Why go to such trouble; why not alert directly?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `cheese()`, it returns a function.

So, when you do:

```
var x = cheese();
```

`x` now contains a function reference.  When you then do:

```
alert(x);
```

you're doing an alert on that function reference (which isn't generally a very interesting thing to do because it doesn't execute that function).

---

If you wanted to execute that function, you would do this:

```
function cheese() {
     return function() {
         alert('hello cheese');
     };
 }
 var x = cheese();    // x now contains the inner function that cheese() returned
 x();   // will run the returned function which will execute the alert() in the function
```

Comment: You're telling me that doing somethin like `var x = document.getElementById('x')` assigns the function rather than call it? That doesn't make any sense.....

Comment: @Isaiah - No, that's not what I said at all.  `var x = cheese();` executes `cheese()` and what `cheese()` returns is another function that has not yet been run.  You have to execute that returned function itself if you want it to run.  That's what `x()` does.  It executes the function that `cheese()` returned.

Comment: ah, sorry misunderstanding from original question

Answer (score 0):

Now `x` is a function so you need to invoke it

```
var x = cheese();
alert(x());
```

---

Also since you want to alert the value returned by `x`, probably you want to return a value from the inner function instead of calling an alert - other wise first the alert in the inner function will be shown then an alert saying `undefined` will be shown as the inner function is not returning anything.

```
 function cheese() {
     return function() {
         return ('hello cheese');
     };
 }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://hello%20cheese)

Comment: Even if I don't put alert (x()); and instead write it like x(); it displays a pop-up "Helo Cheese".  Do you know why? I thought to display a pop-up you need alert function as in alert (x());

Comment: because your x function calls alert. Seems like you still need to learn some general basic programming concepts. Learn how to step-debug code and you will learn faster.

Comment: What is Step-debug code. Any book or website you recommend to lean basic programming.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a function along, assign it to your variable like so:

```
function foo() {
    alert("hello");
}
var bar = foo;
```

Then call the function like so:

```
bar();
```